# Apple touch icon showing in Simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an icon named apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory. When we tap Add to Homescreen from safari, it shows my icon in Simulator. But in device it shows screenshot.

Comment: check ur icon name because it is case sensitive, it will work fine in simulator but not in device@dev

Comment: So this is about web development? And not iOS, Objective-C and Xcode?

Comment: this is in iOS, not web development. I am running a local server, localhost from iPhone device.@Maththias

Comment: @sanjeet apple-touch-icon.png is the name which i gave